# VS Code producing different outputs on re-running the code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying a simple Fibonacci series program using memoization on VS code, but upon rerunning, the output is switching between all 0s and actual output.
Here's the code

```
int fib(int n, int *arr)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        arr[n] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    if(arr[n]>0)
        return arr[n];
    int a = fib(n-1, arr) + fib(n-2, arr);
    arr[n] = a;
    return a;
}
int fibo_1(int n)
{
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
    fib(n, arr);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    delete [] arr;
}
int main()
{
    int n=10;
    fibo_1(n);
}
```

There is no pattern, it just randomly switches to 0 and actual output.
Different outputs :

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.996 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.287 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.834 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.862 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.791 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.797 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\" && g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci && "c:\Users\naman\Google Drive\Coding\CodeBlocks\Code Blocks\"fibonacci

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.8 seconds
```

But when I am not using recursion, but dp approach, everything works fine.

```
void fibo(int n)
{
    int *a = new int[n];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;
    cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " ";
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    delete [] a;
}
```

What is happening?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour related to out-of-bounds memory access.

Comment: Really good, and strange, example of UB

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/oYrajW

Comment: @Naman Mehta This if statement if(arr[n]>0) invokes undefined behavior. The array does not have an element with the index n.